# How to create points grid on a 3d surface with geometry polygonz in postgis?

Tags: postgis, sql, vector-grid, citygml

I am using 3dCityDatabase that imports CityGML buildings to postgresql as polygonz surfaces. In order to carry out an analysis I need to create points on these building surfaces. How can I do that? Which postgis functions or sql statements should I use for this purpose?

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here.  Are you trying to create a point cloud?  A very simplistic answer would be to create a grid of points and get the maximum Z value from the surfaces at that point.

Comment: I would have said, use ST_PointOnSurface, since the manual says it would give you back a point guaranteed to be on the surface. When I checked it though, it doesn't seem to work for polygons (it does for lines) because you get back a 2D point. Might be a bug in postgis.

Comment: @tilt [ST_PointOnSurface](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointOnSurface.html) works on Polygons and MultiPoligons, although I'm not sure if that's what OP is looking for, ST_PointOnSurface returns a POINT guaranteed to intersect a surface, but the meaning of surface is in the mathematical sense, so this point is anywhere on the boundary of the three-dimensional object, it's NOT the topmost point of the object [in the Z axis]. Maybe first getting ST_Zmax and then ST_3DClosestPoint will be helpful if that's what OP is asking for, but let's wait for OP feedback.

Comment: @FranciscoValdez my mistake, I meant to say PolygonZ doesn't work. For example: SELECT ST_AsText(ST_PointOnSurface('POLYGON Z((0 0 0, 0 5 1, 5 5 1, 5 0 0, 0 0 0))'::geometry)); returns "POINT(2.5 2.5)"

Comment: @FranciscoValdez I want to create point grid on buildings faces as x,y,z. I am adding a picture to show what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution ! Surfaces could be subdivided by rectangles and triangles (rectangles often are considered as two triangles).

Every piece has base vertex A0 (x0, y0, z0) and two neighbor vertices A1 and A2. Make base vectors

V1 = A1 - A0
 V2 = A2 - A0
To make regular grid points inside this piece of plane, just calculate

P(u, v) = A0 + V1 * u + V2 * v
where u and v are equally-spaced parameters in range 0..1. Additional limitation for triangles

u+v <= 1